# How is audio stored in Java

Tags: java, audio

This is a quick question, how is audio stored when it's in a byte array, like when a image is stored in a byte array there is three(Red, green, blue) bytes per pixel. So how is a audio stored in a byte array?

Thanks,
Liam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various possible encodings that are supported in Java. See:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.Encoding.html

The most simple form is PCM coding, in which each sample is a linear number that represents the sound waveform (which could be 1 byte for 8-bit encoding).

You also have to consider the number of channels (1 for mono, 2 for stereo). So 16-bit PCM-encoded stereo sound will require 4 bytes per sample, for example.

Answer (score 2):

It's a combination of signals (analog / digital) having a unique frequency for each and every tone. And as it's said in the previous answer, yes, Pulse Code Modulation (PCM) is supported in java.